# Debug VBScript from MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass, Change DefaultAppPool registry

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, msscriptcontrol

I have ASP.NET application where I use MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass to execute VBScripts. However, breakpoints ('stop') are ignored when Eval() function runs the script. I'd like to see JITDebugger triggered, which would allow me to use Microsoft Script Debugger to debug the script. Has anyone had similar issues?

EDIT: After some investigation I found that due to our IIS settings (we are using Windows Authentication) ASP.NET worker process runs as DefaultAppPool and does not have same privileges or registry set as logged on user. So I guess the question now is "How to change regsitry keys for DefaultAppPool user?"

EDIT2: I asked this question in separate thread and got an answer:
[How to change registry keys for DefaultAppPool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385168/how-to-change-registry-keys-for-defaultapppool/23385221?noredirect=1#23385221)

Comment: Does using the correct command run do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to "[Debugging script in MS Script Control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c73463c3-be6d-4464-8e54-6394ca8cbead/debugging-script-in-ms-script-control?forum=vsdebug)" list some relevant options and registry values.

If those hints do not help, try to isolate the culprit by systematic checks. Can you debug

1. a console script without a Script Control
2. a console script using code via the Script Control
3. an ASP without a Script Control

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. 1. I can debug VBScript from cmd, 2. I can debug VBScript using ScriptControl (Eval or Run) from C# console application, 3. I can debug my ASP.NET project, but ScriptControl.Eval ignores breakpoint if the code is running in my ASP.NET project