# How to change registry keys for DefaultAppPool?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

Worker process of our ASP.NET application runs as DefaultAppPool which does not have access to registry keys of logged-on user and cannot debug VBScript invoked from C#. Can I add registry keys to DefaultAppPool user account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DefaultAppPool is not an account, it's an app pool. Inside that app pool you can define which account it runs under (advanced settings / Identity)

Assign it a windows account that has sufficient privileges. Normally you would create a windows account especially for the purpose.

Comment: Now, next step is to create your own app pool with that Identity and assign it to your web application. In other words, leave the DefaultAppPool for everything.... default.... and create a special app pool for your web application / registry access.